# Alamofire - POST request with JSON giving 301

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swift4

I want to send POST request with JSON, I'm expecting JSON object with auth_token and refresh_token in response. My code looks like this:

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    "Authorization": "Basic " + data.toBase64() //data is just string needed for authentication
]

// this should be a JSON
let parameters = [
    "code": self.code,
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "redirect_uri": "populi://callback"
]

Alamofire.request("https://populi.pl/api/v1/auth/token", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { response in
    print(response.request)
    print("\n3 RESPONSE : \(response)")
    print("\n3 POST : \(response.response)")
    print("\n3 DATA : \(response.data)")
    print("\n3 RESPONSE RESULT : \(response.result)")
    print("\n3 RESPONSE RESULT VALUE : \(response.result.value)")
    print("3 ERROR : \(response.error)")
}
```

Yeah, I print a lot of things, that's because I'm new to networking.
**In response I'm getting 301 moved permanently.** Why? I have no idea what's wrong. Is this wrong JSON in parameters or maybe something with redirecting? I should get 200 and JSON in response.

Comment: is this for Oauth?

Comment: @hardikdevios yes 

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
func getData(){
 let todoEndpoint: String = Your url
        let params: Parameters = [yor parameters]
        let headers: [String : String] = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ]
 Alamofire.request(todoEndpoint, method: .post, parameters: params,headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)
                    print(json)

                    break
                case .failure(let error):

                    print(error)
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with "/" at the end of request URL.

Answer (score 0):

I was using URLSession for requests and was getting 301 for 1 request
then I tried Alamofire and still got the same response and at the end, I figured out that issue was that I was not appending `/` at the end of endpoint